# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Blobs are not cacheable

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, blobs, notsupportedexception

After adding `java.sql.Blob` field to one of my objects the hibernate persistence manager is now throwing `Blobs are not cacheable` exception.

Any idea how to solve this other than disabling the cache. I tried making the field transient but of course with no success.

BTW I use the latest Spring Framework.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Exception? DB? Have you tried turning off caching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

1. if you don't need the relevant blob data cached, move it into a secondary hibernate object which is not cached
2. if you do want the data cached (in which case i would assume it has a limited size), then you can use the hibernate type which maps the data to/from a byte[] ("binary" i believe) - http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/

Comment: @MattBanik - if you go the binary route, just make sure someone doesn't try to save a 2GB image.